# issue with displaying proper output in PHP

Tags: php, forms, select

I trying to make search option based on a SELECT box and user input (both are mandatory). But in the following code both correct and wrong input are displaying as wrong input. Can someone please explain what is wrong in the code.

Here is HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="selectOpt">
                  <option>Select a list</option>
                  <option value="one">ID</option>
                  <option value="delName">Dealer Name</option>
                  <option value="medName">Medical Name</option>

            </select>
<input type="text" name="uinput" placeholder="Enter Search Key"/>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">search</button>
 </form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['selectOpt']) && !empty($_POST['uinput'])){


        if($_POST['selectOpt']=='one'){
            $id = $_POST['selectOpt'];

            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$id)){
                echo "not valid";

            }else{
                echo "valid";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "Enter Value";
    }



}
```

Comment: What do you get for output, and what is the input you are passing?

Comment: you have two mutually exclusive conditions. If `selectOpt` equals "one" then it can't also be a number (the `preg_match` condtion)

Comment: if I am entering a numeric value then also it is showing as wrong input (which supposed to be correct)

Comment: You are never checking the value of `$_POST['uinput']`. Maybe you used the wrong variable on the `preg_match`?

Comment: preg_match  why u check  if($_POST['selectOpt']=='one') .. This

Comment: @chris85 Yes.. you are right, now its working fine. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `/^[0-9]*$/`, which is written to require a sequence of zero or more digits, doesn't match any of the possible values for your select box, which are all alphabetic strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST">
<select name="selectOpt">
                  <option>Select a list</option>
                  <option value="one">ID</option>
                  <option value="delName">Dealer Name</option>
                  <option value="medName">Medical Name</option>

            </select>
<input type="text" name="uinput" placeholder="Enter Search Key"/>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">search</button>
 </form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['selectOpt']) && !empty($_POST['uinput'])){


        if($_POST['selectOpt'] == "one"){

            $id = $_POST['selectOpt'];


            if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$id)){

                echo "not valid";

            }else{
                echo "valid";

                   echo $input = $_POST['uinput'];
            }
        }
        else{

          echo "PLEASE Enter Proper and Valid Search  ";

        }

    }
  else{
        echo "PLEASE Enter Value ";
        }



}

?>
```

Comment: i dont understand why you used preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/" ... this .. if You taking an Value from option .. dropdown ... then why you check again ... i think you dont need to check   if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$id)){
....

Comment: You Can check the uinput in preg_match instance of ... id